# Are sys.modules[__name__].__doc__ and __doc__ always the same?

Tags: python, python-module

I am trying to access the module docstring from within the same module it is defined. Practical example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
"Module docstring that explains what the script does."

import argparse as ap

parser = ap.ArgumentParser(description=__doc__)
...
```

I have always used `__doc__`, but I later stumbled upon some code using `sys.module[__name__].__doc__`. The two objects appear to be the same, but I am wondering if they are **always** the same. In other words, is the following:

```
>>> sys.module[__name__].__doc__ is __doc__
True
```

always true? Can I safely use `__doc__` in my example instead of `sys.modules[__name__].__doc__`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In practice they will be the same unless you go out of your way to make them different.

If you assign to `__name__` then you can make the expression refer to a different module:

```
"""My doc string"""
import sys

print(__doc__)
__name__='sys'
print(sys.modules[__name__].__doc__)
```

will print two different doc strings.

Alternatively, you could leave `__name__` alone but delete your module from `sys.modules` and then import another module with the same `__name__` (or in Python 2.x use `reload()` to reload the module after editing the docstring). If you held onto a reference to a function in the old module you could still call it and `__doc__` will be the old value while `sys.modules[__name__].__doc__` is the new one.

So they could be different, but only if you work at it.